# Running UPDATE statement inside a WHILE loop in SQL takes forever to run

Tags: sql-server

I have table which contains about 10 Million records. I am trying to update this table inside a while Loop in 1000 chunks as below:

```
DECLARE @totalRecordCount INT
DECLARE @midCount INT
DECLARE @Chunksize INT

set @totalRecordCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabletemp) 
set @ChunkSize = CEILING(@totalRecordCount/1000)+1 -- Divide the total into 1000 chunks
set @midcount = @totalRecordcount
while @midcount > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE top(@Chunksize) a 
    set a.x = b.x
    FROM TableTemp a
    INNER JOIN
    TableTemp2 b on a.id = b.id 
    WHERE a.x is Null

    SET @midCount=@@ROWCOUNT
END
```

I tried putting a select statement before @@ROWCOUNT to see how much time it takes to reach there, but the query keeps running forever. When I run single update statement with the respective @Chunksize, it runs in 13 secs max, but in a loop, it keeps running forever.

I also replaced UPDATE with SELECT to see whether the loop is operating correctly or not and found it working well.

Not getting why the UPDATE takes forever to run, please help!

Comment: which version of sql server you using??

Comment: Your query is not chunking the results.  It is doing one really big update.

Comment: Is @midcount initialized when you start the while ? Also as gordon already mentioned the update does all in one go, there is no chunking in your code

Comment: Missed to mention, yes Midcount is initialized to totalRecordCount

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: use like below `update top (@chunksize) rest of the query `

Comment: I have edited my question, I am using Top(@chunksize) only.

Comment: seems @midCount is always >0, you need to reset that parameter, and any reason to put `update` inside a `while` loop? regardless of any reasons, you need to set `@midCount` as a auto decrement parameter, such as put `@midCount = @midCount -1` after `update`

Comment: `WHERE a.x is Null AND b.x is NOT NULL`

Comment: I am setting it inside the loop to @@rowcount, problem is, it takes too long to execute the update statement that it dint even reaches to @@rowcount statement

Comment: b.x is never null because I am using a Temp Table b where all records have  valid values

Comment: @Aashi, how do you know it did not reach the `@@rowcount` ?

Comment: _"I tried putting a **select statement before** @@ROWCOUNT to see how much time it takes to reach there, but the query keeps running forever."_ - this makes your loop infinite

Comment: Is there any guarantee that " b.x" is not null?

Comment: yes b.x is not null for sure, I have inserted data into it table b so that there is no null

Comment: Is your real code surrounded with BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN? Anyway you should analyze whether it is **1)** slow (reads?writes?specific actual execution plan?) **2)** infinite (bug? data?) **3)** locked. Problem can't be solved without understanding of nature of the problem.

Comment: A new finding, same code executes well when I pass Chunksize as static value like UPDATE top (1000) a, but when I use UPDATE top(@Chunksize), it takes forever to run the update

Comment: And actual `@ChunkSize` value when you run whole script is ...?

Comment: This code is very brittle. If there is even 1 row in a that doesn't have a match in b your code will never finish. And not sure why you are breaking this into 1,000 chunks. It would be better to determine the optimal chunk size and then run however many updates it takes.

Comment: @SeanLange sometimes it is necessary to break it into chunks. I am doing the same when moving (deleting and inserting) rows from one table to another, to prevent the transaction log from running full and allow other scripts to do their stuff

Comment: I understand the reason for breaking it into chunks. But this code has a fixed number of chunks. The right way to chunk stuff is to determine the size of the chunk, not the number of them. If there are 1,000 rows this will run 1,000 updates of one row each.

Comment: @Ivan Startostin - Actual chunksize when I am running the script is 17131

Comment: Compare actual/estimated execution plans. Could be it uses scan+hash when \@chunksize is big/undetermined at compile time. But uses seek+loop when \@chunksize is predefined and small.

Answer (score 0):

This will update up to 1000 rows each loop. I am not 100 % sure it will work better than 1  big update though(maybe if you include a DELAY):

If you create an index on ID in both tables, this will probably not be necessary. This is however the script to achieve what you are trying. If ID is not unique, you will run into problems for sure.

```
DECLARE @midCount INT = 1
DECLARE @Chunksize INT = 1000

WHILE @midcount > 0
BEGIN
  WITH CTE as
  (
    SELECT top(@ChunkSize) a.x, b.x newxvalue
    FROM TableTemp a
    JOIN TableTemp2 b
    ON a.id = b.id 
    WHERE a.x is Null and b.x is not null
  )
  UPDATE CTE SET x = newxvalue

  SET @midCount=@@ROWCOUNT
  --IF @midcount = @Chunksize WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' -- 5 sec delay
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have index on a.x

In case of one big update, it could be done with one full table scan.

In case of chunks you would have scan ALL rows in each iteration, that have been updated previously (because row order in scan will not be changed). E.g. update would be done with approximately NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS full table scans

Answer (score 0):

Updating in chunks seems to take longer time, instead of that when I updated without chunks, it ran much faster. Also adding indexes helped.

Updating in chunks gets stuck after few loops not sure for what reason.